# Highlighting a Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to figure out the best and easiest way to highlight a selection of cells from a table.

```css
#A1lnk, #B1lnk {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><a id='A1lnk'>A1</a></th><th colspan="2"><a id='B1lnk'>B1</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1-1</td><td>A1-2</td><td>B1-1</td><td>B1-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1-3</td><td>A1-4</td><td>B1-3</td><td>B1-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1-5</td><td>A1-6</td><td>B1-5</td><td>B1-6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><a id='C1lnk'>C1</a></th><th colspan="2"><a id='D1lnk'>D1</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1-1</td><td>C1-2</td><td>D1-1</td><td>D1-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1-3</td><td>C1-4</td><td>D1-3</td><td>D1-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1-5</td><td>C1-6</td><td>D1-5</td><td>D1-6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><a id='E1lnk'>E1</a></th><th colspan="2"><a id='F1lnk'>F1</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E1-1</td><td>E1-2</td><td>F1-1</td><td>F1-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E1-3</td><td>E1-4</td><td>F1-3</td><td>F1-4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E1-5</td><td>E1-6</td><td>F1-5</td><td>F1-6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see I have **essentially** got two columns, A1 and B1. The contents are very simple but suffice to say the actual contents will not be that simple.

I want to be able to click B1 and all the cells below it are highlighted, highlights are the easy part, actually selecting the correct cells is much harder.

I will have multiple other small tables adding C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1 etc. So there could be a few extra but only ever in columns of two. They will cascade in the rows and so still be part of the parent `table` but I'm just trying to figure out the best way to go about it, since the table creates them in rows and not columns.

Comment: Had no idea that was a feature! Added the snippet in. I have tried a couple of things but I'm extremely confused on how to select the cells. With CSS and using nth I am still very much a newbie! At best I can get two cells to appear highlighted only if it's A1

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like you said, however the code gone very long, that's why I have removed some rows.

```js
var a1lnk = document.getElementById('A1lnk');
var a2lnk = document.getElementById('B1lnk');
var a3lnk = document.getElementById('C1lnk');

var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');

var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

function unhighlight () {
    b1.removeAttribute('h');
    b2.removeAttribute('h');
    a1.removeAttribute('h');
    a2.removeAttribute('h');
    c1.removeAttribute('h');
    c2.removeAttribute('h');

}

var b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
var b2 = document.getElementById('b2');



function highlightA () {
    unhighlight();
    a1.setAttribute('h', true);
    a2.setAttribute('h', true);
}
function highlightB () {
    unhighlight();
    b1.setAttribute('h', true);
    b2.setAttribute('h', true);
}
function highlightC () {
    unhighlight();
    c1.setAttribute('h', true);
    c2.setAttribute('h', true);
}

a1lnk.onclick = highlightA;
a2lnk.onclick = highlightB;
a3lnk.onclick = highlightC;
```

```css
#A1lnk, #B1lnk, #C1lnk {cursor: pointer;}

td[h] {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><a id='A1lnk'>A1</a></th><th colspan="2"><a id='B1lnk'>B1</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="a1">A1-1</td><td id="a2">A1-2</td><td id="b1">B1-1</td><td id="b2">B1-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <th colspan="2"><a id='C1lnk'>C1</a></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td id="c1">C1-1</td><td id="c2">C1-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope, this should work for you.

Comment: This is more or less what I managed to cook up, except you did it with the second column as well!

Comment: H is not a valid attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class for header instead of different `id`s. Then on click of header get it's index. Using this index you can easily select the cells below it using `nextUntil()` method and `:nth-child` pseudo selector and highlight them like following.

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).parent().index(),
        a = index * 2 + 1,
        b = a + 1;

    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil(':has(th)')

    tr.find('td:nth-child(' + a + '), td:nth-child(' + b + ')').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.header {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><a class="header">A1</a></th>
        <th colspan="2"><a class="header">B1</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1-1</td>
        <td>A1-2</td>
        <td>B1-1</td>
        <td>B1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1-3</td>
        <td>A1-4</td>
        <td>B1-3</td>
        <td>B1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A1-5</td>
        <td>A1-6</td>
        <td>B1-5</td>
        <td>B1-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><a class="header">C1</a></th>
        <th colspan="2"><a class="header">D1</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1-1</td>
        <td>C1-2</td>
        <td>D1-1</td>
        <td>D1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1-3</td>
        <td>C1-4</td>
        <td>D1-3</td>
        <td>D1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1-5</td>
        <td>C1-6</td>
        <td>D1-5</td>
        <td>D1-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><a class="header">E1</a></th>
        <th colspan="2"><a class="header">F1</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E1-1</td>
        <td>E1-2</td>
        <td>F1-1</td>
        <td>F1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E1-3</td>
        <td>E1-4</td>
        <td>F1-3</td>
        <td>F1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E1-5</td>
        <td>E1-6</td>
        <td>F1-5</td>
        <td>F1-6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks fantastic! However, I'd only have them into two columns and C1 & D1 would below A1 & B1, then below that E1 and F1 etc.

Comment: Show me your html @user2195574

Comment: Let me know that my updated answer helped you or not. @user2195574

Comment: I ended up adding a unique class indentifier to each 6 block of cells, I could then use thaat class to highlight or remove the colouring. Since I'd had these held in an array through php I was looping through them and adding them.